# What's the purpose of the bootstrap property on the @NgModel decorator?

Tags: angular

I think I have a basic understanding about Angular, including NgModules. 
After several readings, including the official documentation I don't understand what's the actual purpose of the bootstrap property on the @NgModule root module definition.

Every component, including the root component, needs to be included on its declarations array to be available for rendering. 
As my understanding, this should work somehow like:

- for a given template.
- inspect the list of available components (from the declarations list)
- using their selector to select an element on the template.
- render those matched components.

What I cannot understand is why are we required to include the root component(s) on the bootstrap property to be able to render it?
The above procedure wouldn't be enough? After all, Ng still needs to use the root components' selectors to figure out where to render it on the index.html file.

Obviously, this is merely an "academic" question.
Any insights?

Comment: *"bootstrap - a technique of loading a program into a computer by means of a few initial instructions which enable the introduction of the rest of the program from an input device."* - [google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=define+bootstrap&rlz=1C1GCEA_enAU762AU762&oq=define+bootstrap&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.5472j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: ask google about "angular 5 custom decorator", e.g. https://blog.angularindepth.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d